# MUI5 TextField not affected with the RTL direction

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, direction

I used RTL in my app with material-ui v4 and it was working correctly.

```
import React from "react"
import { create } from "jss"
import rtl from "jss-rtl"
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from "@mui/styles"

// @ts-ignore
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] })
// @ts-ignore
function RTL(props) {
  // @ts-ignore
  return <StylesProvider jss={jss}>{props.children}</StylesProvider>
}

export default RTL
```

Now, I upgraded to MUI5. but rtl is not affected on my textFields and some other components.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [documentation](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/) Here are some steps that need to do for working `RTL` correctly:

**1. HTML** : Make sure the `dir` attribute is set on the body, otherwise native components will break:

```
<body dir="rtl"></body>
```

As an alternative to the above, you can also wrap your application in an element with the `dir` attribute:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div dir="rtl">
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**2. Theme:** Set the direction in your custom theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl',
});
```

**3. Install the rtl plugin** : When using either `emotion` or `styled-components`, you need `stylis-plugin-rtl` to flip the styles.

```
npm install stylis stylis-plugin-rtl
```

In case you are using `jss` (up to v4) or with the legacy `@mui/styles`package, you need `jss-rtl` to flip the styles.

```
npm install jss-rtl
```

Having installed the plugin in your project, MUI components still require it to be loaded by the style engine instance that you use. Find bellow guides on how you can load it.

**4. Load the rtl plugin**

*4.1 emotion* : If you use emotion as your style engine, you should create new cache instance that uses the `stylis-plugin-rtl` and provide that on the top of your application tree. The `CacheProvider` component enables this:

```
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';

// Create rtl cache
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: 'muirtl',
  stylisPlugins: [rtlPlugin],
});

function RTL(props) {
  return <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>{props.children}</CacheProvider>;
}
```

*4.2 styled-components* : If you use `styled-components` as your style engine, you can use the `StyleSheetManager` and provide the stylis-plugin-rtl as an item in the `stylisPlugins` property:

```
import { StyleSheetManager } from 'styled-components';
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';

function RTL(props) {
  return (
    <StyleSheetManager stylisPlugins={[rtlPlugin]}>
      {props.children}
    </StyleSheetManager>
  );
}
```

*4.3 JSS* : After installing the plugin in your project, you need to configure the JSS instance to load it. The next step is to make the new JSS instance available to all the components in the component tree. The `StylesProvider` component enables this:

```
import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@mui/styles';

// Configure JSS
const jss = create({
  plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()],
});

function RTL(props) {
  return <StylesProvider jss={jss}>{props.children}</StylesProvider>;
}
```

[image: Edit Direction Material Demo]